# CS file from WSDL

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, wsdl.exe

I'm trying to create working CS file from WSDL - my command is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>wsdl /out:"f:\tmp\crmws.cs" http://myserver/myorg/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?singleWsdl /u:user /p:pass /d:dom
```

CS is being generated but with following messege:

```
Warning: This web reference does not conform to WS-I Basic Profile v1.1
```

And many warnings saying that namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization' is improper. Ofc generated CS is useless because I can't connect to CRM with it. Does anyone succeded with connection like this to CRM 2016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRM 2016 operates on WCF services and I was used to WS that was in CRM 4 and 2011. I'm not sure if wsdl.exe should work in this case or not but svcutil.exe works.